# Javascript - Remove event listener when function triggered is using a debounce mechanism

Tags: javascript

I have a function that triggers an action on screen resize:

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
            // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier            
            window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(function () {
              if ( $videosContainer.attr('data-video-hosting') === 'youtube' ) {                    
                resizeVideo(netVidX, netVidY, cryptoVidX, cryptoVidY, 'youtube');         
              }
            }, 250));
          } else if (window.attachEvent ) {
            // For IE 8 and earlier versions
            window.attachEvent('resize', debounce(function () {
              if ( $videosContainer.attr('data-video-hosting') === 'youtube' ) {
                resizeVideo(netVidX, netVidY, cryptoVidX, cryptoVidY, 'youtube');                    
              }
            }, 250));
          }
```

The debounce mechanism is defined as below:

```
// Smart debounce. Source - https://gist.github.com/vincentorback/9649034
// it works the exact same way as you'd expect, except it only fires once the keypress event is idle for XX ms 
function debounce(fn, wait) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(this, arguments)
    }, (wait || 1));
  }
}
```

As this function is called repeatedly, I would like to remove the listener/unbind it BEFORE I add it (again). It's in a slider of videos and I need to re-set the resize listener because some local scoping and the fact videos don't have the same dimensions eahc time...long story...)

In jquery I could do something along the lines of:

```
$video.off('resize').on('resize', function(e) {
```

In javascript I can use removeEventListener

```
if (window.removeEventListener) {
              window.removeEventListener('resize', functionToUnbind, false);
            } else if (window.detachEvent) {
              window.detachEvent('resize', functionToUnbind, false);
            }
```

But my issue is that due to where debounce is located, I don't manage to make removeEventListener work.

I tried putting all the "debounce block" inside a new function called functionToUnbind in order to be able to use the standard removelistener method as shown just above, but it does not work.

```
launchStuffForLatestSliderVideo();
function launchStuffForLatestSliderVideo() {
     //remove first any lingering/remaining/existing resize listener on the videos
if (window.removeEventListener) {
     window.removeEventListener('resize', functionToUnbind, false);
} else if (window.detachEvent) {
     window.detachEvent('resize', functionToUnbind, false);
}

function functionToUnbind() {
   debounce(function () {
              if ( $videosContainer.attr('data-video-hosting') === 'youtube' ) {
                resizeVideo(netVidX, netVidY, cryptoVidX, cryptoVidY, 'youtube');                    
              }
            }, 250)
}

//reset a new event listener for the latest video
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
   // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
   window.addEventListener('resize', functionToUnbind);            
 } else if (window.attachEvent ) {
   // For IE 8 and earlier versions
    window.attachEvent('resize', functionToUnbind);
 }
```

}

How should I remove the listener every time before re-setting it? i think the issue comes from the debounce but I'm not sure

Comment: The issue may be that you have `debounce(function (){...})` returns a new function every time you call it. So you should either store that value into a variable. `window.lastDebounce = debounce(function (){...})` then later use same for add and remove

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks fore the suggestion. I am quite rookie in javascript/jquery so your suggestion makes sense but could you give a more detailed example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the way you're trying to use it, each resize event will have a different reference to `timeout` variable.

Since you're always setting the event handler on a global `window` object which has exactly one instance, you might change `timeout` to be in a global scope so that it too has a single instance.

To do that, you should change your `debounce` function to look like this:

```
var globalResizeTimeout;
function debounce(fn, wait) {
  clearTimeout(globalResizeTimeout);
  globalResizeTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    fn.apply(this, arguments)
  }, (wait || 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks i understand. I ´ll try today

Comment: I see you added things about the timeout but the core issue is how to remove the event listener each time before creating a new one. Should i  use window.removeEventListener like in my attempt in the question ? On which function ?

Comment: Yes, the change I provided is supposed to work with your last example and just replace the `debounce` function